# Invalid cast Eception unhandled by user code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I run the site following errors occured:
  System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Conversion from string "kumar" to type 'Short' is not valid."

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Namespace wbdsproject

Partial Class frmprofile
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim proCon As OleDbConnection
    Dim proCmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim prodr As OleDbDataReader
Dim username As String
Dim userid As Int16
#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "

'This call is required by the Web Form Designer.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()

End Sub
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

#End Region

    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, Me.Load
        'Put user code to initialize the page here
        '        maillink.NavigateUrl = "mailto:saranya@gmail.com"
        Dim proselqry As String
        username = Session("loginuser")
        lblusername.Text = username
        userid = Request.QueryString("userid")
        'Response.Write(userid)
        proCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Discussion Forum\database-WBDS\SampleForum.mdb")
        proCon.Open()
        If Session("loginuser") = "" Then
            Response.Redirect("frmlogin.aspx")
        End If

        proselqry = "select * from tblprofile where uid='" & userid & "'"
        proCmd = New OleDbCommand(proselqry, proCon)
        proCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        prodr = proCmd.ExecuteReader
        If prodr.Read Then
            lbldob.Text = prodr("dob")
            lblquali.Text = prodr("quali")
            lblinterest.Text = prodr("interest")
            lbladdress.Text = prodr("address")
            maillink.Text = prodr("emailid")
            maillink.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" & prodr("emailid")
            lblzip.Text = prodr("zip")
            lblphno.Text = prodr("phno")
        End If
    End Sub

 Private Sub btnmodify_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmodify.Click

    Response.Redirect("frmregmodify.aspx?user=" & username & "&userid=" & userid & "&page=frmprofile")

End Sub

Private Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


End Sub
End Class

End Namespace
```

at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToShort(String Value)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast a `String` returning function into a `Int16` in this line

```
userid = Request.QueryString("userid")
```

Apparently, your return is not numeric. You can either change that from the source if you have control over it or change change the `userid` type to `string`.

I would suggest using a user defined function to test if the requesting querty string is numeric before casting to an `Int16` datatype.